# Ubuntu oracle-xe wont start at system boot

Tags: oracle, ubuntu, oracle11g, linux-mint, oracle-xe

I've successfully installed oracle-xe 11g2 on linux Mint 17.3 and during config process (**/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure**) i choose to load database at system boot.
And when I check **/etc/default/oracle-xe** file, I have the following :

```
#This is a configuration file for automatic starting of the Oracle
#Database and listener at system startup.It is generated By running
#'/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure'.Please use that method to modify this 
#file

# ORACLE_DBENABLED:'true' means to load the Database at system boot.
ORACLE_DBENABLED=true

# LISTENER_PORT: Database listener
LISTENER_PORT=1521

# HTTP_PORT : HTTP port for Oracle Application Express
HTTP_PORT=8080

# Configuration : Check whether configure has been done or not
CONFIGURE_RUN=true
```

But it doesnt start at boot, I have to manually start it by a **sudo service oracle-xe start**

Is there anything I can do ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok found it.

I Have to add user to dba group.

```
sudo usermod -a -G <groupname> username
```

Comment: sudo   usermod -a -G dba username